# Is there a mechanism or app or technology to verify user controls public key?

Tags: wallets, security, public-key

I read somewhere that there is a way for me to verify that a given individual owns a public key.  Unfortunately, I don't know where that article was nor what term to search for.

For example, I want to create a platform where someone can sign up and create an account (with their public key) and then I can verify that said user actually owns the public key.  Is there a way for me to ping them like a 6 digit code to their public key address? lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this article -
https://www.toptal.com/ethereum/one-click-login-flows-a-metamask-tutorial

Basically, you can sign a message with a nonce (any value that changes every time you need verification, e.g. timestamp) and send the signature to the backend for verification. On the backend, you should get the address used to generate the signature and compare it with the user-claimed address (public key).